# getting segfault when I return a vector of pointer to structure

Tags: c++, vector

I was trying to split a string and insert the tokens in a vector of pointers to structure as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

struct A {
    std::string pMessage;
};

std::vector<A*> splitQuery(A a) {
  std::vector<A*> split_queries;

  std::stringstream        ss(a.pMessage);
  std::string              item;

  while (std::getline(ss, item, ',')) {
    A inputPacket = {item};
    std::cout << item << std::endl;
    split_queries.push_back(&inputPacket);
  }

  return split_queries;
}

int main()
{
    A a = {"Hello,there"};
    std::vector<A *> split_queries = splitQuery(a);
    std::cout << split_queries.size() << std::endl;
    for (auto &s : split_queries) {
        std::cout << "elements " << s->pMessage << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

The problem is that I am getting a segfault and I don't why exactly. The split is working correctly. But I don't know what is wrong.

```
Hello                                                                                                                                                             
there                                                                                                                                                             
2                                                                                                                                                                 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

---

## Update and correction

I actually updated the code by using Uniquer_ptr now it is dynanically created so it's on heap right? and therefore it wont be destroyed after push_back.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>
#include <sstream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

struct A {
    std::string pMessage;
};

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> splitQuery(A a) {
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> split_queries;

  std::stringstream        ss(a.pMessage);
  std::string              item;

  while (std::getline(ss, item, ',')) {
    std::cout << item << std::endl;
    split_queries.push_back(std::unique_ptr<A>(new A({item})));
  }

  return split_queries;
}

int main()
{
    A a = {"Hello,there"};
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> split_queries = splitQuery(a);
    std::cout << split_queries.size() << std::endl;
    for (auto &s : split_queries) {
        std::cout << "elements " << s->pMessage << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The pointers you are storing in the array are to temporary variables. When the function splitQuery has exited, they no longer exist but you dereference them later.

Comment: If you need to stop objects from being deleted after going out of scope, then you'll need to handle the lifetime of that object yourself. So, just make pointer by new operator instead of `A inputPacket = {item};`

Comment: thank you so much for ur help. I understand. Well I learned something new. I am fairly new to c++. Thanks a lot

Comment: please dont add the fix to the question. Imho you should rather post it as answer. As it stands now your edit makes the question rather unclear. I mean your question now reads as "i had this not working code, i fixed to to this working code, please check if it is ok", but thats not the question the answers are adressing (anyhow review request should go to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ). I wont reroll your edit but suggest you to do so

Comment: Your line `std::unique_ptr<A>(new A({item}))` could be replced with `make_unique<A>({item})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem boils down to your storing a pointer to a variable with *automatic* storage duration, and that variable is destroyed despite the pointer to it being retained. Then line

```
A inputPacket = {item};
```

declares such a type, and this goes out of scope after the `push_back` statement.

As such then the behaviour of your code is *undefined*.

A possible fix is to use `std::vector<A>` as the type, at the expense of some value copies. This *would* work since your `A` lends itself well to being copied. If that's not acceptable, then use a vector of a smart pointer type such as `std::unique_ptr<A>` with refactoring around the construction of each instance of `A`.

Comment: sorry for the question. Why would the unique_ptr<A> solve the problem?

Comment: Because unique_ptr owns its pointee and takes care of deleting it.

Comment: @ClaudeF: you'd have to switch the storage of each `inputPacket` to *dynamic*, and passing ownership of that memory to the `vector`. I wouldn't do it that way though: I/O is normally the bottleneck in code that does it.

Comment: unique_ptr<A> is a smart pointer that will delete the object it points to when it goes out of scope, so you don't have to worry about it, and using pointers would solve your problem as object dynamicaly allocated don't go out of scope.

Comment: Actually using pointers will solve your problem and `unique_ptr` helps you not to bother about deleting the pointers.

Comment: @Sheric: It might be helpful if you write out the solution based on that. I'd upvote it.

Comment: I updated my question with the recommendations of Bathsheba

Comment: @ClaudeF Don't correct the question, it prevents others from understanding the original question. BTW, make sure there is a space between two `>` in template usage not to be confuesd with `>>` operator. Like this: `> >`.

Comment: @Sheric: That's no longer required since C++11, although some firms (not mine) insist on the old style. A nice break of the C++ *maximal munch* rule.

Comment: @Bathsheba Nice to now! Thanks. And I've just posted an answer as you said.

Answer (score 1):

```
A inputPacket = {item};
```

Creates an instance of `A` in local scope of `while`, so it will be deleted when the scope of while ends. (i.e.: Once when each loop finishes.) Therefore, when you're using the pointers later, They are already deleted.

You have to manage the lifetime of variable yourself, by manually reserving memory for them:

```
A *inputPacket = new A({item});
```

and avoiding to use pointer to a local object. However, in this case you'll have to manage the end of lifetime yourself, too. It means you'll have to delete the pointers somewhere. A nice idea to automate this is using `unique_ptr` Define your return type as:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A> >
```

then create unique pointers and push them into the vector:

```
split_queries.push_back(std::make_unique<A>({item}));
```

This way you'll be safer working with pointers.

Comment: Upped, although do take a look at `std::make_unique`.

Answer (score 0):

Your **A inputPacket** is allocated on the stack (local variable). When exiting your function **split_queries()**, the A instance is destroyed (destructor called) (moreover your are using only one instance of A declared in the loop).
=> you must allocate your A instance on the heap (**A* inputPacket = new A(item);** and do not forget to deallocate it in the main
or use a vector of A (or share_ptr) instead of a vector of A* (which will copy each instance in the vector)